# « Trier sur le volet » : de quel volet s'agit-il ?

Tags: vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, histoire, origine-ou-raison

Je cherche le sens historique du mot *volet* dans l'expression « trier sur le volet ». De quel volet s'agit-il ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

D'après [Linternaute](http://www.linternaute.com/expression/langue-francaise/137/trier-sur-le-volet/) :

> Au Moyen Âge, le “volet” était une voile qui servait de tamis pour trier les graines. Au XVe siècle, il se transforma en une assiette de bois dans laquelle on triait les pois et les fèves. "Trier sur le volet", c'est donc "trier méthodiquement", opérer une sélection.

D'après [Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/trier-sur-le-volet.php) :

> Au Moyen Âge, un *volet* était un tissu si fin et léger qu'il pouvait "voleter" au vent. Il était utilisé, entre autres, pour fabriquer des tamis servant à trier les graines, tamis qui, par extension, sont eux-mêmes devenus des *volets*.

Le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/volet) n'est qu'à moitié d'accord. S'il rapproche bien « trier sur le volet » de l'usage de *volet* au sens d'un tamis, il s'agit d'un type de tamis différent (*volet* I.C.1.a) :

> Couvercle de récipient, tamis en forme de claie, planchette servant au tri des graines et des menus objets.

Le volet est donc pour le TLF un couvercle qui pivote, comme un *volet* de fenêtre, et qui correspond au sens suivant du verbe *voler* (I.B.4) :

> [Le sujet désigne un inanimé naturel ou fabriqué] Être projeté, déplacé dans l'air en y passant avec une grande vitesse, de manière autonome ou en étant lancé par la main de l'homme.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je crois que tu n'as pas compris (donc ça ne devait pas être clair) et du coup tu as changé le sens de la partie que j'ai ajoutée. Le TLF donne un sens différent pour *volet* (et par là une étymologie un peu différente pour *trier sur le volet*), un volet serait un tamis en bois et non en tissu.

Comment: @Gilles: Ah! Désolé, ça n'était pas clair pour moi en effet. Es-tu sûr que la définition suggère que le la partie filtrante soit nécessairement faite de bois ? Je pense que l'origine de *volet* donnée par le TLF est la même que celle des *volets* qu'on met aux fenêtres et indépendante du matériau utilisé pour le crible.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Dans le sens de tamis, un volet est effectivement appelé ainsi parce que c'est un couvercle qui peut pivoter, comme un volet de fenêtre. Le TLF mentionne aussi le *volet* en tant qu'étoffe, voile (sens I.A.) mais ne cite pas ce sens comme pouvant être un tamis.

Comment: Oui, on a donc compris la même chose. Et j'ai plutôt tendance à croire que le TLF a raison.

Comment: @Gilles: J'espère que la formulation est claire maintenant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez *Maintenant* je pense que c'est clair.